# Where should function attributes go?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, attributes

Suppose I want to mark a non-inline function with `[[gnu::cold]];` should the attribute be placed in the declaration in the header, or should it go with the definition in a source file? Assume that I will not be using LTO and simply want that specific function to be optimized for binary size and not execution speed.

header example:

```
[[gnu::cold]] void rarely_called_func();
```

source file example:

```
[[gnu::cold]] void rarely_called_func() { ... }
```

Also, which position in the declaration/definition should it be:

```
/* A */ int /* B */ func () /* C */;
```

Comment: This does not seem like a C question to me...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala GCC definitely allows C functions to have custom attributes.

Comment: Not with that syntax.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fine, assume I wrote `__attribute__((cold))`.

Comment: That format is supported as an extension in gcc and clang and will be enabled by default for C2X in gcc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the attribute is seen by the compiler, it cannot use the attribute in its optimisation. If you don't put the attribute in the declaration, then the compiler cannot see the attribute. Conclusion: In order for the compiler to use the attribute for optimisation, you must put the attribute to the declaration of the function (in the header file).

Comment: `__attribute__((cold))` appears to work on definitions too if you put it before the function name.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hmm strange. I removed the paragraph about that.

Comment: How are you accomplishing this? I seem to get no errors or warnings regardless of which syntax I used. I am testing this using GCC 7.4 on linux x86-64.

Comment: @KevinZ It appears that the `not allowed on a function-definition` error is just a peculiarity of the syntax.

Comment: @eerorika I just updated my question, with more questions. I find that no warnings are generated for "attribute on definition" when I use position (A), some warnings occur when I use position (B), and everything warns when I use position (C).